# Render dictionary with foreach

Tags: c#, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api2

I've got a dictionary that has been serialized by WebApi2 so that the key is the object name and the value is the value.

How can I make knockout render that with it's foreach binding?

[image]

I tried to use `$data[0]` for the key and `$data[1]` for the value, but that didn't work.

```
<table id="context-data" class="table-striped properties">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Properties">
        <tr>
            <th data-bind="text: $data[0]" style="text-align: right"></th>
            <td data-bind="text: $data[1]"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` binding needs an array and you can use the [`Object.keys` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get  an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.

Then you can use the `$data` to display the property name and array indexer syntax on your `Properties` object to get its value (`Properties[$data]`):

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Object.keys(Properties)">
    <tr>
        <th data-bind="text: $data" style="text-align: right"></th>
        <td data-bind="text: $parent.Properties[$data]"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Note: you need to use `$parent` to access the `Properties` inside the foreach.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CXv22/).

Comment: thank you! Do you think that I should change to objects that have Name/Value fields or is the current way a good JSON solution?

Comment: It depends. If you plan to use your Properties as an array in multiple places in your app then it would make sense to turn it into a real array of key/value pairs. Otherwise if you use more your `Properties` as an object/dictionary then I wouldn't change it.